# How to create an ordinary square using OpenGL ES (c++)? (give an example, please)

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

[image]

In the picture you can see the method that is in the loop. It sets a certain background color and clears it (most likely).

I created the Android Native Activity C ++ project, which is very difficult to find information. It is difficult to understand how to bring an ordinary square to the screen.

Give an example, please, or skibe a link to how it's done

Comment: SO is not a tutorial or teaching site. It's a site for answering *specific* programming related questions - where the asker has done the basic homework herself. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compatible across all OpenGL versions:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(x, y, w, h);
glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Haters gonna hate.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but works like Scissors or Clipping Object.
Tell me, please, where can a find some book about that (except documentation)?
Thanks!!!

Comment: The documentation is a great resource for learning about OpenGL ES. There are tons of examples available on the web. Try integrating one of them then read in the doc what the example does. Play around a little, scale something, rotate it, change color, resize window etc.